# Word that describes a person who may be incorrectly assumed an expert?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word was seen used in the context of a person recommending a book.

A critic responded, claiming the author had no real expertise, and that the content of the book should be taken with "a grain of salt".

The implication is that by writing the book, the author is an expert on the subject matter. The critic's stance was that shouldn't be an assumption. He used this word to describe the author.

I do recall looking the word up in the dictionary at one point, and if memory serves, this is (more or less) how the word was defined:

> A person who perceives himself to be an expert (particularly in the
>   arts), but that possesses no actual expertise.

What is this word I'm looking for?

Comment: Could it be _hauteur_?

Comment: If an *S* word will do too, then *supercilious*. Unless-perhaps you're thinking of *Hubris?*

Comment: I'm thinking that person is an ***imposter*** - but not to be confused with "Imposter Syndrome" where one secretly feels like they're not qualified to do the work they do.

Comment: It is none of those three. Remember, I'm only *partially* certain it starts with an H.

Comment: Maybe they are a ***wannabe*** (although this is very informal).

Comment: You may be thinking of *humbug* but most definitions suggest that the person is aware of his deception.  Also *hokum* refers to the scientific sounding nonsense (but not the proponent) and also dos not suggest that the purveyor is deceived.

Comment: Ghost writer? "A ghostwriter is a writer who writes books, articles, stories, reports, or other texts that are officially credited to another person" A fraudster?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've found the word from the original conversation.

The word is **[dilettante](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dilettanteish?qsrc=2446)**:

> A person who claims an area of interest, such as the arts, without
>   real commitment or knowledge.

Comment: I don't think *dilettantes* necessarily perceive themselves as experts.

Comment: Agreed with Peter Shor. A dilettante is a dabbler, one with a superficial or uncommitted interest in many subjects, but not necessarily one who pretends to expertise. The definition you provide is not the one on the page you link, either.

Comment: The definition from this Answer comes from [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dilettante). The word is used in Portuguese as well, and I don't know it as meaning "pretending expertise".

Comment: I've updated the question title and description of the situation in which I saw the word, in the hopes of more accurately describing what it was I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for ***hubris***?

this word would fit the bill.

Another related appropriate term is ***megalomaniac***

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[charlatan](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/charlatan)*

> someone who professes knowledge or expertise, esp in medicine, that he or she does not have; quack

Answer (score 0):

I'd side with the "charlatan", who certainly is an impostor, but maybe an "amateur" (from French), who is a person with no profound knowledge of a subject, though interested in it (as opposed to "professional"), only dubbing in the subject, will suffice?
In answer to some other post, "hauteur" literally means "haughty attitude", which is not applicable here.